# MySQL eliminate duplicates beyond Distinct / Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I realize distinct or group by can eliminate duplicates, but I would like to take it a step further. Is there a simple way, where if a field is not unique, to not show it at all? Rather than simply summing it down to a single row, I want zero rows with the non-unique value.

I could probably put together a stored procedure for this, but am hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: Are you looking for NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a having

```
select SomeColumn
from MyTable
group by SomeColumn
having count(someOtherColumn) < 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you `group by` and `having` with `count` to find out the value which are unique and then use an `IN` to get corresponding rows:

```
select *
from your_table
where col in (
        select col
        from your_table
        group by col
        having count(*) = 1
        );
```